# How to create a test case for a Linked List?

Tags: java

I'm writing a function to delete duplicate elements in my LinkedList but I'm having trouble testing it. I've also tried creating a getter method to find my head instead of getting it as list(0), however that has not worked either.

```
import java.util.*;

class LinkedList{
  LinkedList next = null;
  int data;

  //constructor
  public LinkedList(int data){
    this.data = data;
  }

  void appendToTail(int data){
    LinkedList end = new LinkedList(data);
    LinkedList n = this;
    while (n.next != null){
      n = n.next;
    }
    n.next = end;
  }

  void deleteDupes(LinkedList n){
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    LinkedList prev = null;
    while( n!= null){
      if (set.contains(n.data)){
        prev.next = n.next;
      }
      else{
        set.add(n.data);
        prev = n;
      }
    }
    n = n.next;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.appendToTail(4);
    list.appendToTail(1);
    list.appendToTail(5);
    list.appendToTail(2);

    list.deleteDupes();

    LinkedList head = list(0);
    while (head != null){
      System.out.println(head);
      head = head.next;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below scenarios you can have for linked list testing

1. List with one node or 2 nodes
2. Null
3. Empty List
4. Linked list with a loop
5. List with all dups
6. No duplicates
7. The list could encounter integer over flow, incase low memory